# angularjs location.search ie9 ie8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am a newbie to AngularJS and I'm trying to read query string key value pairs using $location.search. The following code works on Chrome, IE10 and Firefox:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
});

 app.controller('ParamController', function($scope, $location, $window) {
     console.log($location.search()['term']);
 });
```

On IE8/9 the page is immediately re-displayed with '#!' in url eg. from /demo/angularJS/index.html to /#!/demo/angularJS/index.html

Is there a way in AngularJS to read and parse querystring parms in IE8/9?